# crystal report is not showing data

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net, crystal-reports

I am using

```
Report.Bill objRpt = new Report.Bill();
        objRpt.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(DT1);
        objRpt.Database.Tables[1].SetDataSource(DT2);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

to print the crystal report which have two data table but it debug successfully. But on load crystal report viewer it is not showing data on crystal report.
On crystal report data source it has single data set that have two data tables.

Comment: On first glance and without more information: you don't need to refresh the Viewer.